# 'catkin build' gives 'command not found

Tags: catkin, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have ROS Indigo Desktop Full installed from binaries on Ubuntu 14.04.2.

I've been reading about the catkin make system, and am lead to believe there are 3 variations:

- catkin_make
- catkin_make_isolated, and
- catkin build

I'm familiar with the first two and have used them for my projects, but I would like to make use of `catkin build` but I get an error `catkin: command not found`. There is no `catkin` script or executable in the `/opt/ros/indigo/` folder structure.

What could be going wrong?  Is there something else I need to install?

Cheers,
Nap.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207433/%27catkin-build%27-gives-%27command-not-found/) by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2015-04-20

Post score: 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `catkin build` command is part of the `catkin_tools` package. On `apt-get` the package is called `python-catkin-tools`.

The documentation for the package can be found here: http://catkin-tools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Since the package was officially released, I have completely stopped using `catkin_make`. It is a great package!

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 13

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2015-04-20**:
@jarvisschultz : Thanks!!

**Comment by [mwycliff](https://answers.ros.org/users/35940/mwycliff/) on 2018-06-19**:
I issued this command in the terminal, and it worked:

```
sudo apt-get install python-catkin-tools
```

Thank you!

**Comment by [jeremylevasseur](https://answers.ros.org/users/59484/jeremylevasseur/) on 2020-09-15**:
The command that solved it for me was:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-catkin-tools
```

I was missing the python3 specification.

**Comment by [Prachetas04](https://answers.ros.org/users/87896/prachetas04/) on 2021-10-23**:
Err:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu focal/main amd64 python3-catkin-tools all 0.5.0-1
404  Not Found [IP: 2605:bc80:3010::134 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-catkin-tools/python3-catkin-tools_0.5.0-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2605:bc80:3010::134 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

This is the error that shows up while running the "sudo apt-get install python3-catkin-tools" command.
how do I solve it?

**Comment by [shrini96](https://answers.ros.org/users/104316/shrini96/) on 2022-05-09**:
It has been ages, but for someone else also looking for the answer:

https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing.html

First you need to add the repositories and then do apt install.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*catkin: command not found*

catkin_make is working for me but "catkin init" or "catkin build" did not work in noetic version ubuntu 20.04.

So I Installed python tools

> sudo apt-get install python3-catkin-tools

I got error with "osrf-pycommon" distribution was not found and is required by catkin-tools

so I install osrf-pycommon

> sudo apt-get install python3-osrf-pycommon

And Now, catkin is working well and good.

Thanks for the other answers.

---

Originally posted by [prudhvirajstark](https://answers.ros.org/users/76531/prudhvirajstark/) with karma: 11 on 2021-06-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1